# Activity id: cannot specify id in an insert call - Need solution

Tags: lead-conversion

I have got the "Lead conversion" written in a custom manner (visuallforce and controller), when converting a Lead to an Account, I am getting **Activity id: cannot specify id in an insert call** error however multiple Accounts(associated Contacts and Opportunities) being created. How do I get rid of this and moreover, I need to know why is this error raising.

Another is that, is there a way to **stop** a **button** functioning after a **single click**.

```
       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Record Owner"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!lead.ownerId}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Send Email to the Owner"/>
          <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!issendEmailOwner}"/> 
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
          <apex:outputLabel value="Account Name"/>
          <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block" style="position:relative;left:2px;"> 
               <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>   
               <apex:selectList value="{!AccountNames}" size="1">
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!ExistingAccounts}"/>
               </apex:selectList>
          </apex:outputPanel>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
           <apex:outputLabel value="Opportunity Name"/>
           <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block" style="position:relative;left:2px;"> 
               <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>   
               <apex:inputText value="{!OpportunityName}"/><br/>
               <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!isCreateOpportunity}" /> Do not create a new opportunity upon conversion.
           </apex:outputPanel>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >  
          <apex:outputLabel value="Converted Status"/>
          <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block" style="position:relative;left:2px;"> 
               <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>   
               <apex:inputField value="{!leadConversion.Convert_Status__c}"/>
          </apex:outputPanel>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >  
          <apex:outputLabel value="Reason"/>
          <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block" style="position:relative;left:2px;"> 
               <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>   
               <apex:inputField value="{!leadConversion.Reason__c}"/>
          </apex:outputPanel>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >  
          <apex:outputLabel value="Comments"/>
          <apex:inputtextArea value="{!leadConversion.Comments__c}" rows="2" cols="50"/>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    </apex:pageBlockSection> 

    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Task Information" collapsible="false">
       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Subject"/>
          <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block" style="position:relative;left:2px;"> 
               <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>   
               <apex:inputField value="{!taskFields.Subject}"/>
          </apex:outputPanel>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Status"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!taskFields.status}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Due Date"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!taskFields.ActivityDate}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

       <!--<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="To Date"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!taskFields.RecurrenceEndDateOnly}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="From Date"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!taskFields.RecurrenceStartDateOnly}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>-->

       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Priority"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!taskFields.Priority}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Notes Category"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!taskFields.Notes_Categories__c}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Description Information" collapsible="false">
       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="Description"/>
          <apex:inputtextArea value="{!taskFields.Description}" rows="5" cols="60"/>
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

 </apex:pageBlock>
```

```
public with sharing class LeadConversion_AC 
{
String LeadId;
public LeadConversionClass_AC(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    LeadId = controller.getId();
    leadConversion = [select id,Name,
                                FirstName,LastName,
                                Company,status,Phone,
                                Reason__c, Comments__c,
                                Admin_Fee__c,
                                Convert_Status__c,Bus_Type__c                                    
                                from Lead where id =: controller.getId()];
    OpportunityName = leadConversion.Company+' -'; 
    taskFields = new Task();  
    taskFields.Notes_Categories__c = '2-Member Call Complete';
    String leadName = leadConversion.Company;
    accountRecords = [Select id,Name from Account where Name Like : leadName];
    taskRecs = [Select id,WhatId,WhoId from Task where whoId =: LeadId];
    eventRecs = [Select id,WhatId,WhoId from Event where whoId =: LeadId];        
}

public Lead leadConversion{get;set;} 
public Task taskFields{get;set;} 

public List<Task> taskRecs{get;set;} 
public List<Event> eventRecs{get;set;} 
public List<Note> noteRecs{get;set;} 
public List<Attachment> AttachRecs{get;set;}     
public List<Account> accountRecords{get;set;}

public Boolean issendEmailOwner{get;set;}
public Boolean emailNotification{get;set;} 
public Boolean isCreateOpportunity{get;set;}

public String OpportunityName{get;set;} 
public String status{get;set;} 
public String AccountNames{get;set;}

public List<SelectOption> getExistingAccounts() 
{
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('1','Create New Account: '+leadConversion.Company));
    for(Account ac : accountRecords)
    {
       options.add(new SelectOption(ac.Id,'Attach to Existing: '+ac.Name));
    }   
    return options;
}
public pageReference convert()
{
    if(lead.ownerId == null || AccountNames == null || AccountNames == '' || leadConversion.Convert_Status__c == null || leadConversion.Reason__c == null)
    {
       ApexPages.Message msgAddr = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Please enter the required fields');
       ApexPages.addMessage(msgAddr);
    }
    else if((OpportunityName == null || OpportunityName.trim() == '')&& !isCreateOpportunity )
    {
       ApexPages.Message msgAddr = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Please enter the required fields');
       ApexPages.addMessage(msgAddr);
    }
    else
    {
       try
       {
            Account ac = new Account();
            ac.Name = leadConversion.Company;
            ac.Admin_Fee__c = leadConversion.Admin_Fee__c;
            ac.Business_Type__c = leadConversion.Bus_Type__c;                
            ac.Phone = leadConversion.Phone;                                                                
            ac.Converted_Status__c = leadConversion.Convert_Status__c;
            ac.Description = leadConversion.Comments__c;
            ac.Reason__c = leadConversion.Reason__c;
            insert ac; 
            system.debug('HELLO'+ac);
            Contact c = new Contact();
            c.FirstName = leadConversion.FirstName;
            c.LastName = leadConversion.LastName;
            c.AccountId = ac.Id;
            c.Act_On_Lead_Score__c = leadConversion.Act_On_Lead_Score__c;
            insert c;

            taskFields.whoId = c.id;
            Opportunity op = new Opportunity();
            if(!isCreateOpportunity)
            {
                op.Name = OpportunityName;
                op.AccountId = ac.id;
                //op.closeDate = [Select EndDate From Period Where type = 'Quarter' and StartDate = THIS_FISCAL_QUARTER].EndDate;
                Integer currentMnt = system.Today().month();
                Integer currentQ =((currentMnt-1)/3) + 1;
                op.closeDate = date.newInstance(system.Today().year(),currentMnt + (4 - (currentMnt - ((currentQ -1)*3))) , 1).addDays(-1);
                op.StageName = 'Prospecting';
                insert op;
                taskFields.whatId = op.id;
            }
            if(!(taskFields.Subject == null || taskFields.Notes_Categories__c == null))
                insert taskFields;
            if(taskRecs.size() > 0)
            {
                for(Task t : taskRecs)
                {
                    t.WhoId = c.id;
                    if(!isCreateOpportunity)
                      t.whatId = op.Id;
                    else
                      t.whatId = ac.Id;  
                }
                update taskRecs;
            }   
            if(eventRecs.size() > 0)
            {
                for(Event t : eventRecs)
                {
                    t.WhoId = c.id;
                    if(!isCreateOpportunity)
                      t.whatId = op.Id;
                    else
                      t.whatId = ac.Id;
                }
                update eventRecs;
            }
            /*if(noteRecs.size() > 0)
            {
                for(Note t : noteRecs)
                {
                    t.ParentId = c.id;
                    if(!isCreateOpportunity)
                      t.ParentId = op.Id;
                    else
                      t.ParentId = ac.Id;
                }
                insert noteRecs;
            }
            if(AttachRecs.size() > 0)
            {
                for(Attachment t : AttachRecs)
                {
                    t.ParentId = c.id;
                    if(!isCreateOpportunity)
                      t.ParentId = op.Id;
                    else
                      t.ParentId = ac.Id; 
                }
                insert AttachRecs;
            }*/
            Lead l = [select id from lead where id =: LeadId];
            delete l;

            return new pageReference('/'+ac.Id);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            system.debug('hello Exception'+e);
        }  
    }
    return null;     
}
public pageReference cancel()
{
    return new pageReference('/'+LeadId);
}
```

}

Comment: You will need to be much more specific and provide your code samples or be in risk of the thread being closed for too broad. Currently the only answer anyone can give you is that you cannot insert a record that already exists.

Comment: @Eric I have updated my question with my page and controller. Actually, there are multiple Accounts being created while the page is not redirecting to the **Account Detail Page** & is remaining in the **Lead Conversion Page** itself. If I click **Cancel** in the **Lead Conversion Page**, it is showing that there is no data available (because the Lead is already converted to multiple Accounts)

Comment: Is there a specific line of code called out with that exception?